# How safe is it to plug a resistor on a 12 V transformer?

Tags: resistors, transformer, security

I was thinking about using an old fridge as a seedling cabinet.  I am tempted to use the resistor of an out of order pizza oven plugged on a small 12 V transformer to heat the cabinet.

I didn't do the math yet to know if I could achieve a suitable temperature, because this idea led to my wondering whether **there could be any security issue with such a setup ?**

I am not talking about obvious fire issues of a too hot resistor, I'm rather thinking about potential fire hazard from the transformer.

The transformer is 12 V/5 A, so my understanding is that anything above 2.4 Ω should be ok ?  The resistor being supposed to be about a few tens of ohms, plugging it directly should be safe ?

Comment: Is the 12 volt transformer brand new?

Comment: @Andyaka Well not new as in "manufactured this year", but new as in "never used before".

Comment: The most important thing is that the resistor must be rated to handle the power continuously. Also, add a fuse.

Comment: What sort of transformer is it? It's not an autotransformer hopefully? Is it rated for your input supply (not specified)? Does the transformer need an earth connection to make it safe to use? How competent do you feel you are wiring to AC mains power?

Comment: Does the old fridge have an incandescent bulb to illuminate its interior when you open the door? If so, you might try disabling its door switch, so the bulb is ON whether the door is closed or open. It might provide appropriate heat.

Comment: @glen_geek Great idea !

Comment: @Andyaka The transformer doesn't have an earth connection.  That's a standard 230 V AC transformer for LED strips, AFAIK it doesn't require any sort of competence to wire to AC mains power, or did I misunderstood your question ?

Comment: @JonathanS.Coming from a commercial pizza oven, I assume the resistor is rated to handle very large temperatures for one-hour sessions at least, could longer sessions at very much lower temperature be an issue ?